type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' with shared_preferences
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/localizations.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';

import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import 'functions.dart';
import 'stylesheet.dart';
import 'widgets.dart';

dynamic language, country_code;
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((sp) {
    language = sp.getString('language');
    country_code = sp.getString('locale_region');
  });

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Ebabil',
      localizationsDelegates: [
        AppLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        Locale('en', 'US'),
        Locale('es', 'ES'),
        Locale('fr', 'FR'),
        Locale('it', 'IT'),
        Locale('tr', 'TR'),
        Locale('ar', 'SA'),
        Locale('ja', 'JP')
      ],
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.lightBlue),

      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final Future<bool> is_initialized = IsInitialized();
    is_initialized.then((value) {
      if (value == false) {
        GenerateDefaultPreferences();
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LanguageSelection()));
        });
      } else {
        SynchronizeDLIfSet();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //(...)
  }
}

The runtime error occurs at line 89, when it sets the locale. I tried adding ! at the end of language and country_code but nothing changed.
I put an initializer function inside initState(), but it still gives null. It uses shared_preferences to get and set the values of language and country_code.
The initializer function IsInitialized() is implemented like this:
Future<bool> IsInitialized() async {
  final sp = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  final bool? isInitialized = sp.getBool('initialized');
  if (isInitialized == null) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

Also why does Dart throw an error when a null value appears?

The issue seems to be that country_code is null, you should not use '!' as you do expect it to be null. Instead you should use a fallback to this value, like with '?? "MyCountryCode".
